# Strict weak ordering concept for std::map's key type

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I'd like this class template to require a concept such that the Key type supports strict weak ordering comparison.

```
template <typename Key>
class Map {
    std::map<Key, int> map;
}
```

Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: [`std::strict_weak_order`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/strict_weak_order)? Though I don't know how to use it exactly.

Comment: I've tried using it but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Which compiler did you use? Which version?

Comment: @Damien gcc 10.1.0

Comment: the best thing you can do is document it. No way to check programmatically. You would have to check every possible pair of inputs.

Comment: Notice that `std::strict_weak_order` is mostly semantic, as no checks is done to enforce requirements.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on if you want to use `<` for your comparison primitive or you want to require `<=>`.

If the former:

```
template <typename Key>
    requires std::strict_weak_order<std::less<Key>, Key const&, Key const&>
class Map;
```

If the latter:

```
template <std::three_way_comparable<std::weak_ordering> Key>
class Map;
```

Both of these will do syntactic checks during compile time but also impose the semantic check that the ordering in question is a strict weak order (actually I suppose that's technically missing from the `weak_ordering` wording, but it should be there...)